# PAR::Packer and HTTPS in LWP::UserAgent

Tags: json, perl, ssl

I have a simple Perl which uses LWP::UserAgent to connect to HTTPS and decode JSON result:

```
my $self = shift;
my $text = shift;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $response = $ua -> get ($self -> getReqLink($text));
$response = parse_json($response -> decoded_content);
return decode('utf-8', $response -> {text} -> [0]);
```

It works fine if I run Perl script.
I packed it with pp:

```
pp -c -o maker.exe maker.pl
```

And I get and error if I run maker.exe:

```
JSON error at line 1, byte 1/170: Unexpected character 'S' parsing initial state: expecting whitespace: '\n', '\r', '\t', ' ' or start of an array or object: '{', '[' at Translation/YandexTranslator.pm line 30.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Main question here may be: why should such a solution need to contact Yandex for any translation? AFAIK Yandex is similar to Google and Google translate, but in Russian.

Silly suggestion, but have you tried "split and conquer", ie removing calls to each module to see which one is causing the issue?   (avoid JSON, avoid LWP::UserAgent etc)

Comment: @FtLie Yandex has free translate API, Google doesn't. I think that the problem is in SSL connecting, PAR doesn't pack SSL certificates. But it doesn't work if I add Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem manually.

Comment: What happens if you add the line `$ua->ssl_opts( verify_hostname=> 0);` after constructing $ua? That would avoid SSL verification. Perhaps not a secure solution but could demonstrate if that really is your problem.

Comment: also, are you using strict, warnings, diagnostics? if not, maybe the problem is already there when you run it unpacked, just not saying anything...

Answer (score 0):

1. Always use `-x` when you run PP. It will add run-time dependencies and generate a more reliable executable for you. In my experience, this option can fix many mysterious errors.
2. Add `use warnings` and `use strict` at the top of your code.See if there is any potential problem.